# How can I convert my link_to syntax to use a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view that currently uses a link_to object, using the signature defined in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) thusly:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

I want to convert it to block-style syntax so that I can add several styled elements within the link_to.  I have been trying to use the alternate signature provided in the documentation:

```
link_to(options = {}, html_options={}) do
   #stuff
end
```

but this has been unsuccessful because it does not provide for a `url_options` hash, only `options`.   Is there a way to get the `options` hash to accept my current `url_options`? For example, my current (working) code is as follows:

```
link_to ’Click Me’, { controller: :projects, action: :create, project: { modification: true } }, method: :post
```

and I am trying to get it to work in the following form (in HAML):

```
link_to { controller: :projects, action: :create, project: { modification: true } }, method: :post do
   .heading 'Click me'
    #add some other elements here
```

which gives me the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
```

Alternatively, am I overlooking another way to implement a block within my link_to?  I am new to Rails and to programming, so any help would be appreciated, including suggestions on how to present this question in a more useful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that curly braces have more than one purpose in Ruby. One is to enclose a hash, for example:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}
```

And another is to pass a block to a method, for example:

```
[1, 2].map { |i| i * 2 }
```

In the case of the following code:

```
= link_to { controller: :projects, action: :create, project: { modification: true } }, method: :post do
  .heading 'Click me'
```

Ruby interprets first open curly brace as you attempting to pass a block to `link_to`, when in fact you wanted to create a `Hash`.

Fix this by adding parentheses for `link_to` so that Ruby already sees the first curly brace as part of an argument:

```
= link_to({controller: :projects, action: :create, project: {modification: true}}, method: :post) do
  .heading 'Click me'
```

Comment: Thank you -- this was a helpful reminder of good use of parentheses.  Unfortunately I updated the code exactly as you suggested and now I'm getting a new error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`  I'm stumped by this because I can see that your suggestion clearly conforms to the documentation.

Comment: In the end, the syntax that worked for me was this: `link_to ({ controller: :projects, action: :create, project: { modification: false } }), {method: :post} do`.  That is, I had to move the closing parenthesis to just after the url hash, to differentiate it from the html_options hash.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the link_to signature does provide a url_options arg, even with a block. Here is what the signature looks like in the rails source:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

Really, options and url options are the same thing. Here is what happens inside the link_to method:

```
url = url_for(options)
```

so if the options you pass work for url_for, you should still be able to pass them as well as a block.

The key take away here is that the method with the block and the method without the block are not two different overloaded methods, its just the same method with default args if you choose to not supply an arg.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Rails is getting confused with the parameters. I suspect the nested `{}`s are throwing it off.

One solution is to add `()`s, to make it clear which argument is which.

```
link_to ({ controller: :projects, action: :create, project: { modification: true } }, method: :post) do
   .heading 'Click me'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the simpler path/url helper:

```
projects_path(project: { modification: true })
```